# Получение информации о всех исключениях в приложении

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Пишу журнал ошибок.

Необходимо получать информацию обо всех исключениях, которые произошли во время работы  приложения.

Помимо сохранения текста из `e.getMessage()` при каждом исключении, существуют ли другие способы это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если же нас интересуют необработанные исключения, которые ведут к крашу приложения, то можно воспользоваться методом `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. Для этого в класс `Application` добавляем следующие строки:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("TAG","Сохраняем отчет об ошибке");
            ...
            System.exit(2);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: В `Application` нет метода `attachBaseContext`, но если `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`  поместить в `onCreate` у `Application` работает на ура. Проверял на API 23.

Comment: @Streletz ну почему это нет, `Application extends ContextWrapper`, а `ContextWrapper` в свою очередь имеет `protected` метод `attachBaseContext()`. В любом случае можно естественно вызвать и в `onCreate` ;)

Comment: Прошу прощения. Из-за глюка студии метод просто не отобразился в подсказке.

Answer (score 3):

Да, все верно, необходимо писать лог при каждом нужном исключении. 
Я бы рекомендовал использовать для этих целей log4j http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

В нем есть широкие возможности для настройки.

так же его легко использовать.

```
public class MyClass{

  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

  public ReturnType myMethod(Param p, Param2 p2) {
    ....
    ....
    try {
      ..    
    } catch(MyException e) {
       logger.log("Exceptions happen!", e); 
    }
    ....
  }

  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я сторонник без надобности не подключать ничего стороннее, в java есть какой-никакой логгер, тем более если надо будет то и в log4j и в другие логгеры его вывод можно перенаправить, поэтому рекомендую его.

[Java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

JUL включен в стандарт и поставляется вместе с JDK, поэтому ничего дополнительно скачивать и подключать вам не надо.

Логгер создается вызовом одного из статических методов класса `java.util.logging.Logger`:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingJul.class.getName());
```

Вывод в лог:

```
try {

} catch(Exception e) {
   log.info(e.getMessage());
}
```

По умолчанию JUL пишет в консоль, но это поведение, как и формат сообщений - настраиваются:

```
 LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(getClass().getResourceAsStream("log.properties"));
```

> log.properties

```
# Настройки глобального логгера
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
# Конфигурация файлового хендлера
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = log.txt
```